# Reading Double + EOL from socket input using readDouble

Tags: java, android, sockets, datainputstream

Alright, I'm getting desperate here. I've been searching for an answer to this for going on 4 hours now with no luck. Here's the gist of what I'm doing. I have an android app that connects to another device via sockets. I have my output stream working correctly (the connected device can receive the byte value I send, correctly - so if I send 10 to the device it sees 10). On the flip side, my app receives input whenever it sends a command to the device. The device sees the command and sends back a packet structured [DOUBLE+EOL]. The EOL is specially 0x0A - '\n'.

I was able to get this working with python without much trouble. However, I'm very new Java and haven't quite figured this out. I've tried a number of things and right now and am using `DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())`. I tried using BufferedReader but I was unable to convert the string to a double like I wanted. Here's the important code for the communication I am trying to get to work:

```
if ( send_command( 40 ) )
{
    try {
        final double left_servo_pos = input_stream.readDouble();
        try {
            left_servo_pos_view.setText( Double.toString( left_servo_pos ) );
        } catch ( Throwable t ) {
            left_servo_pos_view.setText( t.toString() );
        }
    } catch ( UnknownHostException e ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Command "40" just tells the device to send the packet of the format specified above. The `catch ( Throwable t )` is just a stand-in for now until I figure out exactly what I'm using (and thus what kind of errors I can have - originally this caught the conversion type errors when I was trying to use Double.parseDouble() ).

So, what happens right now? I get a number of different values showing up in my TextView "left_servo_pos_view". They all end with something around "e-312" which tells me the .readDouble() method is just grabbing a portion of the stream whenever it comes through (so it's getting parts of the actual Double value I'm sending, just not the whole thing).

And that's my problem. I can provide additional details as needed (I'm not really sure what else would be helpful to you). As I said, everything seems to be working except for this part (which is why I haven't provided initialization code or anything else like the functions that set up communication). I can change the input_stream type to whatever is necessary (like I said, I've tried BufferedReader without much luck and now I'm back to DataInputStream.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I ended up solving the issue in a completely different manner than I had predicted. After doing a packet capture of the output from the controller it turns out the data is coming in "little endian" style (still not really sure why, guess that's how the controller implements it). So, I found an Little Endian InputStream class online which I implemented and almost fixed the problem. The first value would be correct and then it would take 8 more values before it was correct again. So, I figured there was something I was missing in the packet and after a closer examination there is an extra byte "00" at the end. So, I added "skipBytes( 1 )" to my code and it is now working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Either you're not sending a double or you're out of sync with the sender. I don't see any need for the trailing \n. I also don't see where you are consuming it, which of course *puts* you out of sync with the sender. I would double-check that you are sending the double with DataOutputStream.writeDouble(), and remove the \n from the protocol completely.

Comment: Let me preface this with I have now solved the problem which I'll add above. The problem with the input is that I'm not able to use "DataOutputStream" or any Java for that matter as it's on a PLC and using a generic sockets module to send the data. However, I will look into your suggestion for future communications use also.

Comment: @user1661109 Exactly as I said. You were *both* (1) not sending a double, at least not one that [`DataInputStream.readDouble()` understands](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)), and (2) out of sync with the sender, which was sending a trailing null that you weren't consuming.